# Set low latency kernel as default in Lubuntu

Tags: linux-kernel, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu and have installed the low-latency kernel. After the booting the kernel used is still the old generic kernel. How can I set the low-latency kernel to be used by default (instead of holding down the shift, and choosing it at GRUB on each boot)?